# Filtering by date YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api

I am using the youtube api for a school project and I am completely new to this API. I would like to know if it is possible to sort comments, likes, and views by date when using the API.

It is necessary for my project that I get data only before a certain date.

Answer (score -1):

If you check the documentation for [comment.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list) you will find that there is no sorting or searching paramaters.

The [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) method will also not let you sort your videos by date.

[search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) however does let you sort for videos by date.  But you can only search on the name of the video or the text in the description.

If you want to do this you're going to have to get back all of the results and sort them out locally.  This API is very limited.